# T SQL Sum from separate Views

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have 3 Views called vQuestion1, vQuestion2, vQuestion3. Each has 2 columns called Outcome and Total.

The Outcome column can have a number of values such as "N/A", "Improved", "Not Improved". Each Outcome has a total score.

```
vQuestion1                vQuestion2              vQuestion3
Outcome      Total        Outcome       Total     Outcome     Total
N/A          12           Improved      10        N/A         5
Improved     10           Not Improved  20        Improved    13
Not Improved 4
```

I need to create a result where the totals are added together to create a result as follows:

```
Total Answers
Outcome      Total
N/A          17
Improved     33
Not Improved 24
```

Please note that not all answers exist in each question, ie Question2 does not have N/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do a `UNION ALL` and then a `SUM`

Something like

SqlServer 2005+

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    vQuestion1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  *
        FROM    vQuestion2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  *
        FROM    vQuestion3
)
SELECT  Outcome,
        SUM(Total) Total
FROM    Vals
GROUP BY    Outcome
```

Or

```
SELECT  Outcome,
        SUM(Total) Total
FROM    (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    vQuestion1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  *
            FROM    vQuestion2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  *
            FROM    vQuestion3
        ) Vals
GROUP BY    Outcome
```

Comment: Thanks Astander, I used your second example and it worked first time! Much appreciated.